# Can you self sign a pyinstaller program so that it doesn't show up as a virus when giving it to other poeple?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, codesign, code-signing-certificate

I am creating a python program and converting it into a .exe with auto-py-to-exe(a gui for  pyinstaller). I uploaded it to my google drive for my friend to download but he cant download it since chrome and google drive thinks its a virus. I couldn't even send it through gmail (I had to use AOl...... funny how AOl does that). I know the file isn't signed and thats whats likely making it look like a virus, I didn't know if there was a way to sign the code so that google doesn't throw hissy fits about it.

Comment: Does [this page](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/Recipe-Win-Code-Signing) from the official pyinstaller GitHub help? And [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/ms537361(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)'s MS's official page on Code Signing.

Comment: @RandomDavis Thank you that does help, but upon reading into it more I realized that it costs 100+ a year to have my file signed using a trusted certificate. Thats so expensive for no reason.

Comment: If there was a way to sign for free and have it automatically (no setup for the end-user) work for the end-user that would be great. I don't need it to have anti-tamper and stuff, I just want to be able to send it to friends and have them be able to use it without their AV or google blocking it

Comment: Does [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/46749/send-exe-etc-file-via-gmail-without-needing-special-actions-by-the-recipie) work for you?

Comment: @RandomDavis yes it does!!!! thank you, Why didn't I think of this before since I do this all the time.